# Form not getting submitted

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to submit a form but it's not working. In the code below it is even changing the color of "Log in" submit button to red when "success" is returned. In the Chrome console it shows nothing and in the network tab it invokes only Ajax call activity:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.ajax_example = {
        attach:function (context) {
            jQuery('#user-login #edit-submit').click(

                function(){

                    var login = jQuery("#user-login #edit-name").val();
                    var pass = jQuery("#user-login #edit-pass").val();


                    //make Ajax call to get authentication details
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        data:{
                            js: 1, 
                            login: login,
                            passwd:pass
                        },
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(data)
                        {            
                            if(data.msg)
                            {
                                alert(data.msg);

                                if(data.msg == "success")
                                {
                                    alert("submitted the form");
                                    jQuery('#user-login #edit-submit').css('color', 'red');
                                    jQuery('#user-login #edit-submit').submit();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        url: "http://localhost/my/user/verifylogin"
                    });

                    //alert('sent data1');
                    return false;
                })
            return true;  
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And the html code of the Drupal form is:

```
<div id="content" class="column">
  <div class="section"> <a id="main-content"></a>
    <h1 class="title" id="page-title"> User account </h1>
    <div class="tabs"> </div>
    <div class="region region-content">
      <div id="block-system-main" class="block block-system">
        <div class="content">
          <form action="/my/user" method="post" id="user-login" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <div>
              <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
                <label for="edit-name">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60" class="form-text required">
                <div class="description">please full name ending with @woodstock.ac.in</div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-item form-type-password form-item-pass">
                <label for="edit-pass">Password <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" id="edit-pass" name="pass" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
                <div class="description">Enter the password that accompanies your username.</div>
              </div>
              <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-gJYws5bihrq8cGOg-bZXiTcd9u5JoTqA4mqiw8nW3jc">
              <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login">
              <div class="form-actions form-wrapper" id="edit-actions">
                <input type="submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Log in" class="form-submit" style="color: red;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this :jQuery('#user-login,#edit-submit').click()

Comment: When you are handling the submmition of form using `ajax` then why you need to submit it, redirect the user on success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of `click()`

```
jQuery('#user-login').submit(....
```

> The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to
>   submit a form.

It's that you are looking for, not click the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
    $( "#target" ).submit();
});
```